# Wordpress custom post having variable number of fields

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Lets suppose I want to create posts of event where each event will have content like following:

Event A

duration of event: 3 days
day 1: Reception and Orientation
day 2: some activities
day 3: conclusion

event pics:
pic 1
pic 2
pic 3

event comments:
comment 1
comment 2
comment 3

Now here is the tricky part, different events will obviously have different content BUT most likely also have different number of days and their day wise activities, different number of pics and different number of comments.

Is it possible to make number of certain fields variable within a post of same post type 'post'? Only clue I have is creating custom post type which have post within them but that is it. Please tell first if it's possible at all, and please ask for clarification if needed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all your requirements are possible.

Second if you do this manually wihout any plugin you need to create metaboxes(alot metaboxes) which contains different different content as well as different dates.but its too hectic and lengthy process. you can achieve this thing with creating custom fields with the help of Acf plugin.

But if you want to use any plugin i personally recommend the Events calendar plguin. it's too good for your requirments.

for more information you can visit below link.
[Click here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/)

Hope it will help you:)

Comment: I am already using acf, if I create a custom field group,  say add event. It has fields duration, day 1 activities, day 2 activities, day 3 activities, pic 1, pic 2 pic 3, comment 1, comment 2, comment 3. How do I make day xx activities into variable like how can some event have days activities upto day 4 and some event may have upto 15 days. same with pics and comments. Do metaboxes help in that problem? I really would prefer not to use any plugin as long as I can help it.

Comment: For this my suggestion is first use this plugin in your localhost and you will get idea how the custom fields are created from plugin. after that you can create your own custom fields through acf. 

Because in comment section i can't give you full info its bit too much to tell. but for short you need to create two custom fields starting date which contain start date second field end date which contain end date of the event.

Comment: My example with event was merely an analogy to give an idea. I have a custom field group of 18 fields, out of which 4 will have different multiples of duplicate fields for example daywise activity could go upto 15 days for some event and 3 for some other event. Here day wise activity isn't something I can put under single textarea field. i want them to be like while have post=> post {while daywise activity have post=>the post } something like mini post under posts

Comment: You need to use ACF repeater plugin for that. it can create a custom field with add rwo button so you add as much row you can for a particular post.

Like you need three fields for a post so you need to add three rows but if you need 8 or 10 row for different post you can add that much fields for that post.

Comment: The repeater option seems like a solution, but I can't find it in field type dropdown. I am using official advanced custom fields plug in. Besides, I have to use the repeated fields inside single.php not some page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142446/discussion-between-appstauq-and-suraj-menariya).